# How to set authenticate Proxy in Selenium Firefox web driver?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

Here is my code for **test.js** script:

```
require('geckodriver');
const config = require("../config/config.json");
var webDriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
var firefox = require("selenium-webdriver/firefox");
var proxy = require("selenium-webdriver/proxy");
var options = new firefox.Options();
options.addArguments("-headless");

var driverFirefox = new webDriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(webDriver.Capabilities.firefox())
    .setProxy(proxy.socks('username:password@proxy_host:port'))
    .setFirefoxOptions(options)
    .build();

call1() {
    try {
         driverFirefox
            .wait(driverFirefox.get('http://IP_Address:PORT'))
            .then(function() {
                console.log("Success!!!!");
            }); 
    } catch (mainError) {
      console.log("Inside try's catch block");
      console.log(mainError);
    }
}
call1();
```

Using above code when I run script test.js I am getting my requested Public IP address instead of Proxy IP address in requested URL (http://IP_Address:PORT).

Below is the code for print requested IP in http://IP_Address:PORT route:

```
const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
console.log('IP: ', ip);
```

Can anyone please suggest me how to get Proxy IP in my script ?